# Sequence of calling registerForRemoteNotifications and requestAuthorization

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification, usernotifications

When should I call `registerForRemoteNotifications()`?

1. In completion handler of `requestAuthorization(options:completionHandler:)` ?
2. In `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` ?